# Does the US Senate need a majority of total members or members present to pass a vote?

Tags: united-states, senate-rules

Just curious. If the US Senate has a vote that's 48-47 with 5 absentees, does that pass, or what?

Comment: Does this answer your question:? [*How does voting in the US Senate work?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/36088)

Comment: You don't need to spend much time examining the record before you see measures that have passed with fewer than 50 votes.